# Details of Microsoft Office Url protocol?

Tags: ms-office

Microsoft Office Documents register custom url protocol on the client computer.

This is especially used by SharePoint. For example, if I open an excel file, I see the call to this url :

```
ms-excel:ofv|u|https://mycorp.sharepoint.com/Documents/somefile.xlsx
```

Is there any available documentation of this feature?

What are the format and options of these urls?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is limited documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes). These protocol handlers appear to only support `http` and `https` URI.

To summarize, Microsoft office registers the following protocol handlers:

- ms-word:
- ms-powerpoint:
- ms-excel:
- ms-visio:
- ms-access:
- ms-project:
- ms-publisher:
- ms-spd:
- ms-infopath:

To view a document:
`ms-excel:ofv|u|http://contoso/Q4/budget.xls`

To edit a document:
`ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|http://www.fourthcoffee.com/AllHandsDeck.ppt`

To Create a New Document from a template:
`ms-word:nft|u|http://cohowinery/templates/elegance.pot|s|http://cohowinery/presentations`

**There is currently no protocol handler registered on Microsoft Windows to launch Power BI.**
Support is available on mobile platforms (including Windows Mobile) via the `mspbi` protocol handler. The following is a summary of the official documentation which is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-apps-deep-link-specific-location).

Open the Power BI mobile app:
`mspbi://app/`

Open to a specific dashboard:
`mspbi://app/OpenDashboard?DashboardObjectId=<36-character-dashboard-id>`

Open to a specific tile in focus:
`mspbi://app/OpenTile?DashboardObjectId=<36-character-dashboard-id>&TileObjectId=<36-character-tile-id>`

Open to a specific report:
`mspbi://app/OpenReport?ReportObjectId=<36-character-report-id>`

Open a specific report page:
`mspbi://app/OpenReport?ReportObjectId=<36-character-report-id>&reportPage=ReportSection<number>`

Open in full-screen mode (for Windows Mobile devices only):
`mspbi://app/OpenReport?ReportObjectId=500217de-50f0-4af1-b345-b81027224033&openFullScreen=true`

Comment: So those protocols does not support file:// in the URI?

Comment: @RudolfDvoracek it does not appear so at this time. There is no documentation on the topic and hacking at it, I could not make file:// work

Comment: Is there a way to make MS word open two documents with this protocol?

Comment: @Sathish You would have to fire off two separate requests

Comment: Really frustrating that this doesn't support `file://`

Comment: It does support ˋms-word:ofe|u|C:/path/to/file.docxˋ, though. Forward slash, not backslash.

Comment: @AndreasLinnert your suggestion works, but only if there is no spaces in path. Is there a workaround for that also? I tried '+', '%20, but nothing works.

Comment: Is there a scheme for Power BI? I've tried searching but can't find anything except possibly "mspbi" but it seems strange that they wouldn't follow the "ms-" convention.

Comment: @lane the `msbpi` protocol handler only appears to apply to mobile devices. On my Windows 10 machine, with both Power BI Desktop and the Windows Store Version of Power BI this handler is not registered. This seems to be inline with the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-apps-deep-link-specific-location).

Comment: @Silko, did you ever found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

Since i do not have the reputation to comment, here is a solution for local files, which seems to work for me (Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13530.20490) 64-bit):

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\protocolhandler.exe" "ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|file:///C:/path/to/file with spaces.pptx"
```

Important to note are the forward slashes. Also if you use the wrong program, i.e. use `ms-powerpoint` for `.xlsx` files, this will fail. `protocolhandler.exe` is located in the Office root directory, which might be in another location on your system (it's the directory where `WINWORD.EXE`, `POWERPNT.EXE` etc. are located)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open local file, maybe try:

`ms-excel:file:/Users/river/Desktop/2.xlsx`

`ms-word:file:/Users/river/Desktop/2.doc`

...