# Open a .docx document using desktop word

Tags: angular, download, upload, ms-office, protocol-handler

We get .docx documents from a backend server. The users downloads them to their local machine, edits them jusing MS Word/Excel/... and uploads them back.

Is it possible to make angular open the installed Word and register when the user saves the document so that it can upload them back into the backend server?

Comment: You might be able to open the document with the [`ms-word` protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965041/details-of-microsoft-office-url-protocol), but you'll need something like the [File Reader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to determine when the file has been saved. Word will not provide you with a notification and the `ms-word` protocol might not even let you pick where the file is saved since it appears to be http/https only, not `file:///`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. To be precise, only Internet Explorer understands the COM technology on Windows. Other browsers will not let you automate the locally installed desktop Office applications like Word.

As a possible workaround you may consider using [protocol handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965041/details-of-microsoft-office-url-protocol) for Office applications.